# C++ Не работает wide char в консольном приложении при записи в файл (fstream)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, fstream, wchar-t

Не работает запись в файл русских символов. Операционная система английская. Пытался изменять на русский язык систему, толка нет. Чтобы программа выводила русские символы в консоль, помог только один способ: добавление функций _setmode.
Код программы:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define LENGHT_OF_WORD 50
#define NUMBER_OF_WORDS 20

using namespace std;

int main()
{
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
_setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_U16TEXT);
_setmode(_fileno(stderr), _O_U16TEXT);
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, ".1251");

wofstream fout;
fout.open("Words.txt");
wchar_t words[LENGHT_OF_WORD][NUMBER_OF_WORDS];

wcout << L"АБВ!\n"; // проверяем вывод просто в консоль русские "АБВ"

fout << L"ABЫ" << endl; // записываем в текстовик английские "AB" и русскую "Ы"

fout.close();
return 0;
}
```

[image: Скрин 2]
**Скрин 2**
Запуск программы

[image: Скрин 3]

**Скрин 3**
Запись в файл. Видим, что русская "Ы" не записана

[image: Скрин 4]
**Скрин 4**
Изменял язык в настройках системы на Русский и обратно, изменяя этот параметр (чекбокс)